# page.type() inside page.evaluate()

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer, webautomation

I want to type some user details in following input `class`

```
<span class="myClass">
    <input aria-autocomplete="list" role="searchbox" aria-haspopup="true" class="ng-tns-c58-69" 
    autocomplete="off" type="text" aria-controls="pr_id_7_list" aria-expanded="false" aria- 
    activedescendant="p-highlighted-option" placeholder="Pass" size="24" maxlength="16">
</span>
```

First, I tried use `page.$eval()` method to input details

```
let domain = 'input[class=ng-tns-c58-69]';
await page.$eval(domain, (el, value) => el.value = value, pass.name);
```

but it threw error:

```
Error: Evaluation failed: DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 
'input[class=ng-tns-c58-69]' is not a valid selector.
```

Then I used `page.evaluate()` method as

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
    let domain = 'ng-tns-c58-69';
    let elements = document.getElementsByClassName(domain);
    for (let el of elements) {
        el.click();
        el.keyboard.type(passenger[0].name, {delay: 100});
    }
})
```

that gave error saying:

```
Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
```

I am new to puppeteer, Kindly help me.
Thank you.

Comment: How about `input.ng-tns-c58-69` as a selector in the first example?

Comment: @pavelsaman, sorry I realized I shouldn't answer myself. Will you post the solution? (I will delete mine)

Comment: I think you can answer your own question, no problem. Keep it this way.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by pavelsaman, used `input.ng-tns-c58-69` with `page.$eval()` method and it worked. Here is the final code:

```
let domain = 'input.ng-tns-c58-69';
await page.$eval(domain, (el, value) => el.value = value, pass.name);
```